# Dataset declaration - performance test

Tags: vb.net, dataset

First let me start with an example,

```
Public Class EmpDemo

    Public Function getEmpData() as DataSet
    End Function 

End Class
```

Case 1:

```
Dim ds as New DataSet   'A DataSet instance gets created here
ds = EmpDemo.getEmpData()    'Another DataSet instance gets created here
```

Case 2:

```
Dim ds as DataSet
ds = EmpDemo.getEmpData()  'A single instance gets created here
```

Question:

How it will effect page performance if I choose *Case 1* ? How I prove *Case 2* is best choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance difference will be negligible, but Case 2 is obviously the better choice.  Adding code that does nothing useful, in this case creating an object instance that you never use, just pollutes your code base.